# Error in Java 8: 'javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: Certificate chaining error'

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, tls1.2

I try a `tls1.2 connection` to a local Webserver (IIS) over Apache HTTPS client, via `CloseableHTTPClient`. I use a local `cacert-file (jks-File)` that contains the root, the intermediate and even the servers certificates. The certs themselves look fine when checked manually and are accepted by all browsers.

Error:

```
    %% Invalidated:  [Session-2, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: Certificate chaining error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: Certificate chaining error
       at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:6)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:572)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:11)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:74)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.E.a(E.java:307)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.E.a(E.java:121)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.D.r(D.java:223)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.D.a(D.java:198)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:649)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.at.i(at.java:627)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.at.a(at.java:689)
       at com.ibm.jsse2.at.startHandshake(at.java:432)
       at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:404)

and so forth...
```

This code worked so far, until the certs got changed (they got invalid).

After that, the code crashed with the above message. The new root certificate is SHA1-signed, not SHA256. I cannot see if this is the problem, changing this might be a problem (i consume the cert, i don´t manage it).

**EDIT:**
The root ca used is the "Digicert Global Root CA".

Answer (score 0):

I have got something similar one of certificates in chain was expired.
Could you recheck yor logs ?
Maybe one of certs in chain  is invalid ?

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/certificate-chaining-errors-httprequest-node

> A 'certificate chaining error' occurs when the provided chain of
>   certificates cannot be validated.  Here, one of the certificates is
>   "not trusted".

In may case one of cert in chain was expired.